# Programmatically altering table cells (eg. rowspan)

Tags: jquery, html-table

I'll start with my goal.

I am using jQuery and creating a big table of data from data pulled from a JSON file. The rows are years/months, the columns are categories. So, a table of three categories over five years will be three columns by sixty rows.

A single event in the table might span two years - so 24 rows. An event will never span more than one Category (column).

I don't think I can build the table **as** I add data - that'll be a headache to build, debug and maintain - so I think I have to build the entire table, then target the cells programmatically.

My question:

Once the table is built, with all its cells, **is there a way - using DOM-manipulation (jQuery) to alter cells - adding a rowspan - so that, say, 24 cells in one column are now one cell?** (presumably I'd have to delete the now-extraneous 23 cells.)

Sure, in theory, if I build the table virtually, say in a 2-dimensional array - and only write it to the page once its all constructed, but **can I alter it once it's on the DOM?**

Comment: Short answer is yes you can. Beyond that any productive solutions would require seeing exactly what you are working with as a [mcve]

Comment: As this comes back to me after a while, I realize there is an element.remove() function in jQuery.

Comment: Yes and you can use `attr()` or `prop()` to set `rowspan`. The logic involved however still depends on exactly what it is you are working with

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm trying to do:

before:

```
+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+
```

after:

```
+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |
+   +---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |
+   +---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+
```

I figured it out. May not be the most elegant solution, (and, frankly, it highlights a problem that is outside the scope of this question).

```js
function replaceRowSpan(cell, rows) {
  cell.attr("rowspan", rows);
  var rowClass = getRowClass(cell);
  if (rowClass) {
    var rowNum = rowClass.split(/-/)[0].substring(1, rowClass.length - 1);
  }
  for (r = 1; r <= rows; r++) {
    $("tr.y" + (rowNum + r).toString()).remove();
  }
};

function getRowClass(el) {
  var parentClasses = el.parent().attr('class')
  if (!parentClasses) return;
  var classList = parentClasses.split(/\s+/);
  for (var i = 0; i < classList.length; i++) {
    if (classList[i].charAt(0) === 'y') {
      return classList[i];
    }
  }
};

replaceRowSpan(cellElement, 4);
```

```
<tr class="y0-0">
<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="y1-0">
<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="y2-0">
<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
```

So,

- when I have a td cell I want to expand, I pass the element
  (cellElement) and the number of rows (4) to replaceRowSpan().
- replaceRowSpan() adds the rowspan to the existing td, then finds the
  class of the cell's parent tr (via getRowClass() ).
- it then iterates through the rest of the rows, removing their first
  element (nth-child(1)).

It works, but the problem is: **it only works once**.

If I now want to expand a cell in another column (say, row 3, column 3), then the cells are no longer in-alignment, since some rows have 2 cells, and some have 3. So, the index of the cells to remove is thrown off.

And the discrepancy accumulates every time I do this.

after:

```
+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |
+   +---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |
+   +---+   +---+
|   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+
```

I think I may be able to get around it by **counting cells from the right, instead of from the left**. Then it won't matter how many have been replaced with rowspans - as long as I'm always adding data to columns left-to-right only.